# How to mock methods from private objects in a tested class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have created an abstract class for a Rest client class for which I want to write unit tests.

I want to write tests for the `HandleRequest` method below but to be able to test certain situations I need to make sure that `_client.ExecuteTaskAsync` returns a certain value or throws an exception. The private object `_policy` however is created by `Mock<IPollyPolicyFactory>` and is `private` within the abstract class.

The code for the class in question looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractRestClient
{
    private readonly IRestClient _client;
    private readonly IAsyncPolicy _policy;
    private readonly IRestRequestFactory _requestFactory;

    protected AbstractRestClient(RestSettings settings, IRestClientFactory restClientFactory, 
        IPollyPolicyFactory pollyPolicyFactory,
        IRestRequestFactory requestFactory)
    {
        _requestFactory = requestFactory;
        _client = restClientFactory.CreateRestClient(settings);
        _policy = pollyPolicyFactory.CreateAsyncResiliencePolicy(settings);
    }

    protected async Task<T> GetResult<T>(Url url) =>
        await HandleRequest<T>(_requestFactory.CreateGetRequest(url));

    private async Task<T> HandleRequest<T>(IRestRequest request)
    {
        var result = await DoRequest<T>(request);
        if (result.FinalException != null)
        {
            throw result.FinalException;
        }

        if (!result.Result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException($"Error executing request: {result.Result.StatusCode}; 
                {result.Result.StatusDescription}; {result.Result.ErrorMessage}");
        }

        return result.Result.Data;
    }

    private async Task<PolicyResult<IRestResponse<T>>> DoRequest<T>(IRestRequest request) =>
        await _policy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(cancellationToken => _client.ExecuteTaskAsync<T> 
            (request, cancellationToken), Token);

    private static CancellationToken Token => new CancellationToken();
}
```

I have created a class for unit testing `AbstractRestClientTest` which uses an implementation class of `AbstractRestClient` called `MockRestClient`.
Right now my test class contains the following code:

```
public class AbstractRestClientTest
{
    private AbstractRestClient _sut;
    private Mock<IRestRequestFactory> _requestFactoryMock;
    private Mock<IRestClientFactory> _restClientfactoryMock;
    private Mock<IPollyPolicyFactory> _policyFactoryMock;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _requestFactoryMock = new Mock<IRestRequestFactory>();
        _restClientfactoryMock = new Mock<IRestClientFactory>();
        _policyFactoryMock = new Mock<IPollyPolicyFactory>();
        var settings = new MockSettings();

        _sut = new MockRestClient(settings, _restClientfactoryMock.Object, _policyFactoryMock.Object,
            _requestFactoryMock.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void HandleRequest_finalexception_not_null_then_throw_finalexception()
    {
        //How do I mock DoRequest throwing an FinalException?
    }
}

public class MockRestClient : AbstractRestClient
{
    public MockRestClient(RestSettings settings, IRestClientFactory restClientFactory, 
        IPollyPolicyFactory pollyPolicyFactory,
        IRestRequestFactory requestFactory) : base(settings, restClientFactory, pollyPolicyFactory, 
            requestFactory) {
    }
}
public class MockSettings : RestSettings
{
    public override string Naam => "TestSettings";
}
```

Comment: You could describe the problem you run into.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t mock `private` members. This is because the mocking-framework usually uses some mechanism that relies on `virtual` and `override` for a class. A `private` member however can´t be overridden.

In order to achieve that, you´d have to make the `DoRequest`-method `interal virtual` (assuming your assembly has `InternalsVisibleTo`-attribute set to the test-assembly), or `public virtual`.

However from my perspective it seems your `DoRequest` is a bigger concept. Otherwise you won´t need to mock it at all. So your client-code has a dependency on something that should actually be another class - which in turn could be mocked afterwards.